# Django ManyToMany not appearing on pgAdmin

Tags: django, many-to-many

I've created (abridged) two tables:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
        tag_word = models.CharField(max_length=35)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=250)

        def __unicode__(self):
        return self.word

Class Place(models.Model):
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    tag_word = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I can see my Tags field on Django Admin, but not on PgAdmin and they don't return in my Place queryset. What have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: You should see another table named `<appname>_place_tag_word` or something like  that which would have references to the `<appname>_place` model. Also, edit the question with your query to see why it does not return the queryset.

Comment: could you post your code in the admin.py?

Comment: Thanks Karthikr, too many hours in front of the screen and I missed the obvious in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @karthikr in the comments, this data appears separately from the main table itself.

It is stored in another table and the name should be something like `<appname>_place_tag_word` for the above example. Or `<appname>_<tablename>_<columnname>` more generically.